# Lua- garbage collection with a linked list

Tags: lua, linked-list, garbage-collection

I'm working on a project where i'm using a linked list to keep track of some objects. I'm perpetually adding new objects to the list and removing the old ones. I can't seem to be able to get rid of memory leaks during the process though.

```
function linkedlistClass:remove_destroyed()
local current = self.head
local before
for i=1,self.length do
    if current.value.destroyed then
        if current == self.head then
            self.head = self.head.next
            current.value = nil
        else 
            before.next = current.next
            current.value = nil
        end
        self.length = self.length - 1
    end
    before = current
    current = current.next
end
    self.tail.next = nil
end
```

So this seems to be the problematic part of code.The length of the list is definitely counted correctly as I've checked that multiple times.

The list is composed of nodes with value and next attributes.The object which the value attribute points to has a boolean attribute .destroyed which determines if the object should be gotten rid of.

After the method is called the list should be self-contained. The head just points to the second element as it should,the tail points to nil and the list's length behaves as it should.

Somehow the nodes which are left out are not collected ,which leads to memory leaks. I can't seem to get rid of them.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: did you try to call collectgarbage()?

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm actually measuring the memory leak via collectgarbage("count").

Comment: 1. Please indent your code properly. 2. We need to see more code than this to narrow down what's happening. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Ok,i doubt that anyone else will have the following problem but message me if you do i guess.

It turns out that i was using the library 'hc' or 'hardon collider' and i was not removing the objects from the scene.

Comment: well that you're using external libraries would have been valuable information. I think you can delete your post. it's pretty useless to anyone else